# Load sensor - to sense/track a ball movement

Tags: sensor, load, proximity-sensor

Wondering if anyone can give me some directional steer on a project I’m working on for Uni.

In short, My team are working on a project where we want to track the movement of a croquet ball from one shot location on a training mat to another location through the goal.

We’re thinking the best thing might be to use two load sensors that might be linked. The weight of the ball on sensor 1 would have the sensor in “ready” mode, once the ball is hit the sensor would Activate the second sensor which would detect when the balls weight is on it. The objective is to track a couple of things, the goal scored, the speed of the shot and maybe accuracy depending how big the sensor pad might be.

As you can probably tell I’ve pieced this together from some google searches. My main question is would two linked load sensors be the best thing for this? To allow me accurately track the croquet balls movement from one location to another on a fixed training mat?

Thanks for any answers in advance : )

Comment: I recommend providing dimensions for everything -- in detail. We might tend to assume too much. Besides, you know what you are talking about. (After that, I'd expect still more questions as those details become clearer.)

Comment: ***Spec of Croquet Ball and Gate Ball***. I googled to find that Croquet ball is 9.3 cm diameter, weights 1 lb (454g), and gate ball 7.5 cm diameter, weighs 230g. So gateball suits old people better. And I guess cheapy weight sensors and low resolution ADC (8-bit Arduino built in ADC GPIO pin, MCP3008/10 bit, MCP3201 12 bit) should be more than enough.

Comment: And the OP might find the following Q&A useful for reference: ***Sensor to distinguish between different types of pegs on a pegboard***
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/523764/sensor-to-distinguish-between-different-types-of-pegs-on-a-pegboard. In my answer, ***Ref 1 and Appendix A describe the cheapy weight sensor*** I have been using. Cheapy Weight Sensor: https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32669458593.html.

Comment: The OP might also like to consider the ***Load Cell*** approach. Some two years ago, I did a Micky Mouse toy project in weighing a growing plant. The spec is summarized below: (1) Weight range: 0g to 500g, (2) Accuracy < 1g, (3) Speed, 0.1s, (4) ADC, HX711, with Wheatstone bridge, (5) Rpi3B+ with MCP23017, ESP8266-12 WiFi, (6) LCD 20 characters  x 4 lines characters. Ref: (7)https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=227137&hilit=tlfong01+load+cell&start=25#p1397220.

Comment: Perhaps I should modify my plant weighting project hardware to the gateball training set, with ***automatic real time score record***, directly transferred to my grandmother's ***smart phone***.

Comment: Thanks all so far, so the Ball weighs approx 50g, so I’d need a sensor that can easily pickup the ball is resting in the “starting zone” the mat itself is 4 metres long and 1 metre wide with 1 goal (wicket) in the centre on the other end. At the end where the goal is, ideally we want to have multiple or a much larger load sensor to track where the ball comes to rest.

Comment: To continue So I guess we want to track the speed of the shot which might be calculated by connecting the start sensor and goals sensors, a timer between them can calculate speed. The reason for multiple sensors in the goal are is to track the accuracy. Would a load sensor/sensors be the right thing here,?

Comment: Selected comments too far off technical line have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115491/discussion-on-question-by-mollymal-load-sensor-to-sense-track-a-ball-movement).