# How do I effectively trip a digital Hall effect sensor with low current. Magnetic field amplification?

Tags: analog, electromagnetism, physics, hall-effect

This is part of a more complex project for school but here is what you need to know to help me.

- I have a DC voltage from 0-5 volts
- I must include a resistive load.
- The Hall effect sensor trips a digital 0 in the presence 4.9mT of magnetic field.
- I want to be able to sense currents on the uA maybe nA scale.
- Anything I add to my circuit can't change the DC steady-state current.

What do I add to my resistor circuit to "amplify" the magnetic field due to current?

Should I try to make a small DC transformer to get a larger magnetic field?

I am thinking of just adding an inductor in series with the resistor and pointing it at the Hall effect sensor.

EDIT:
This is the hall effect sensor

https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=26&gotoUrl=http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv5021.pdf

It's a drv5021A1.

Sorry my post was confusing I meant to say I must *Include* a resistave load. But I know I will probably be adding an inductive load as well.

Comment: We can't answer this if we don't know what sensor you're using. Please [edit] your question and add a link to the datasheet (not an Amazon / Ali-whats-it ad).

Comment: Max W - Hi, You said: "*I must have a resistive load*". OK I guess this means the previous (unspecified) output stage must only "see" a resistive load. But then your suggested solution is: "*[...] just adding an inductor in series with the resistor [...]*" which will increase the inductance of the overall load and it will no longer be (almost all) resistive. So which is it? Does the load need to be only resistive, or not? Did I misunderstand something? IMHO adding a block diagram (or schematic) to your question, explaining what is driving the load & its constraints, would help readers. Thanks.

Comment: I have reported my test results on both the Allegro and Honeywell Hall Effect sensors in my answer of the Q&A below. Please feel free to ask @tlfong01 for more details. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/523764/sensor-to-distinguish-between-different-types-of-pegs-on-a-pegboard. Cheers.