# How can I set up a reed switch/magnets on an electronic chess board to consistently detect pieces?

Tags: electromagnetism, reed-switch

My goal is to build a chess board that can detect the movement of pieces on it. My current approach that I'm testing is to have a reed switch underneath each square and magnets attached to the bottom of each chess piece. I was inspired by [this article](https://www.hackster.io/lpalcu/foldable-electronic-chess-board-fbe264#toc-sensing-technology-3).

However, in testing, what I'm finding is that when the magnet is dead center on the read switch, the switch is open, not closed! I found [this article](https://standexelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/Reed-Switch-And-Magnet-Interaction.pdf) which was a very helpful overview of why this happens, and what happens in different configurations.

I've considered:

1. Pole facing down - this has the switch off when the magnet is centered on the switch
2. Thin bar magnet roughly equal to the diameter of the piece - this works pretty well given that the piece overlaps the center which gives a good enough margin for error; the problem is that it attracts/repels the other pieces next to it too strongly!
3. Other approaches: RFID (looks more expensive, more complicated to set up, and hard to scan quickly enough), light sensors (requires drilling holes in the centers of the squares which I'd prefer to avoid)

However, I'm still at a loss - is there any clever way I'm missing to set this up so that a piece placed on a square triggers the reed switch, with a solid margin for error (I play a lot of blitz chess)?

Comment: When you say "the switch is open, not closed" do you mean the normally-open switch *stays* open, or that you accidentally bought normally-closed switches and they go open when the piece is in place?

Comment: The normally-open switch stays open I mean. Here's a video of me fiddling with it for a few attempts: https://imgur.com/a/gDapzGR (rigged up to an LED via the Pi)

Comment: What about putting the switches in a different direction, like vertical? Vertical magnet, and vertical switch? the switch may need to be quite close to the board.

Comment: @user253751 vertical reed switch seems to work OK but I don't think I have that much dead space to spare beneath the board :( Also much harder to set up that way, they're pretty fragile.

Comment: I would suggest to try the Hall Effect sensor.

Comment: @tlfong01 Wouldn't a hall effect sensor have a similar problem or no?

Comment: This, at the moment, is all a mechanical problem with how you're using the parts. A Hall Effect sensor would also have a mechanical problem if mounted wrong. We can't remotely solve a mechanical problem and it's not the site for it. Discussions on alternatives don't seem viable until you've identified clearly why the reed doesn't work. VTC for those reasons, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hall effect sensors are more reliable than reed switches and can be much more sensitive. Try a few of those. The only downside to them compared to a reed switch is that a reed switch doesn't require power.

Comment: If you have normally open switches and expect them to close when the piece arrives on the square, make sure the switch is correctly oriented.

Comment: @James: I think Hall effect sensor has many advantages over reed switch. You might like to skim my comments and answer to a similar EESE Q&A below: ***Sensor to distinguish between different types of pegs on a pegboard*** - Asked 1 year ago, Viewed 4k times
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/523764/sensor-to-distinguish-between-different-types-of-pegs-on-a-pegboard/523912#523912

Comment: Try mounting the reed switch vertically in the center of the square, and the magnet with the pole facing down.  A miniature (short) reed switch would work best.

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone for the advice! I ordered a test set of hall effect switches and I'll try them out this weekend. Seems the advantage is that they may be more sensitive + I can orient the hall effect switch any direction I want because it's smaller (3mm on its longest axis instead of 14) and less fragile.

Comment: The hall effect sensors worked great! They're small so I can orient them in an arbitrary direction, and while they seem to only work when any part of the disc magnet is directly over top of them, that's good enough for my case.